Split "Related Lists" component into multiple "Dynamic Related List - Single" components
I am now working on refactoring of Lightning Record Pages in an org where we used to use Page layouts. Of course moving fields was a piece of cake - thanks Salesforce for the upgrade button!
But now I also need to make sure the related lists are not dependent on Page Layouts and I was wondering if there is a way to easily migrate all related lists from a Page Layout to a Lightning record page?
